# Htaccess Redirect within Folder

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect http://www.mydomain.com/site/_dev to http://www.mydomain.com/site/. Any ideas on how to do this using htaccess only?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your .htaccess file in the root of your `www.mydomain.com site`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^site/_dev http://%{HTTP_HOST}/site/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use mod_alias and `RedirectMatch`

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^site/_dev /site/
```